# Is it possible to have magento template files within module folder?

Tags: magento

I am building a module for magento in app/code/local.  I want everything inside this folder.  However, on reading tutorials, it seems that I cannot have my layout xml files and template phtml files in my module directory, they have to be in app/design/...

Am I right in thinking this or can I have my design elements within my module directory?  I want to keep everything in one place.

Comment: Your layout and template files must reside in app/design folder as per Mage standard structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but would require you to create symlinks to the correct paths.

Lets say you have your templates in `app/code/local/Mymodule/design/frontend/mymodule/default` then your can create a symlink with the following

`ln -s /var/www/web/app/code/local/Mymodule/design/frontend/mymodule /var/www/web/app/design/frontend/mymodule`

Unfortunately Magento won’t allow you to use template files that are in symlinked folders by default. You can however enable this using an option in the CMS.

Go to CMS and Choose System > Configuration Then choose Advanced > Develop from the side menu.

Under Template Setting  select YES for “Allow Symlinks”

If you can’t access the CMS then look for this value in the database core settings . Otherwise
you’ll need to temporarily modify a Mage core file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php`

Edit line 240 to this:

```
// if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {

if(strpos($includeFilePath,'..') === false) {
```

This will allow you to access the CMS and update the Allow Symlinks setting as described above. You can then undo the changed file.

Comment: Advise not to do this and use MVC architecture provided by Magento. Symlinks don't work on all OS's and if you need to move server you need to remember to re-add them and you can't package your module up so it installs nicely into other magento installations. Put the template files in the design template folder and the layout files in the layout folder and the code in the code folder. You will not find any module that does this, and it's best to stick to Magento's best practices.

Comment: I agree completely, I don't advise for this to be done at all, I was merely explaining it is possible especially if you develop your modules and use modgit or modman as a means of deployment.